# Error handling with c++

Tags: c++, string, error-handling

I need to do some error handling in c++ that corrects user input if it's a letter or a string. I need to use .at(), .length(), and atoi to handle this. I'm not sure how/where to implement those is the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {


    srand(time(0));
    int number;
    number = rand() % 50 + 1;
    int guess;
    int x;


    for (x = 5; x > 0; x--) {
        cout << "Guess my number, it's between 0-50. You have 5 guesses: ";
        cin >> guess;
        if (guess < number){
            cout << "Your guess was too low" << endl;
        }
        else if (guess > number){
            cout << "You guess was too high" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "You're exactly right!" << endl;
        break;
    }
}   while (guess != number){
    break;
}




return 0;
```

}

Comment: If you're trying to catch errors with the users input then put your error catching code where you get user input. As for the how, I'm pretty sure you are already able to check if a number is less than 0.

Comment: int guess;
cin >> guess;

So - what do you think happens if the user enters a letter?

Answer (score 2):

The best approach to input validation is to write a function that reads into a `std::string`, checks whatever is needed, and only returns a value when it passes the tests:

```
int get_value() {
    std::string input;
    int value = -1;
    while (value < 0) {
        std::cout << "Gimme a value: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        try {
            value = std::stoi(input);
        } catch(...) {
            value = -1;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: "write a function": +1  the mistake of the new programmer is to write god functions.